# How to include WP_Nav_Walker class

Tags: wordpress, wp-nav-walker

I'm using PSR-4 on my classes but when I used `Oyic\Utils\Bootstrap_Nav_walker` which extends the `WP_Nav_Walker` class it throws an error that the class `WP_Nav_Walker` could not be found.

I already required it: `require_once ABSPATH. "wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php";`

```
namespace Oyic\Utils;

require_once ABSPATH. "wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php";

class BS4NavWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
/**
 **/
}
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Oyic\Utils\Walker_Nav_Menu' not found in /app/public/wp-content/themes/basic/library/Utils/BS4NavWalker.php:15